# How to make this strange constraint convex?

Tags: convex-optimization

Does anyone know how to make this constraint convex?

$$\frac{P_{02}{\gamma_{02}}}{P_{01}\gamma_{02} + P_{U_{2}}\gamma_{22} + 1}> P_{U_{1}}\gamma_{13} + P_{U_{2}}\gamma_{23} + 2\sqrt{\gamma_{13}\gamma_{23}P_{U_{1}}P_{U_{2}}}$$ where only $P_{U_{1}}$ and $P_{U_{2}}$ are variables.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you let us know what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried to introduce slack variable but it seems not work.